# cartesian to hyperspherical and hyperspherical to cartesian coordinates transfomation kotlin

Tags: kotlin, math, geometry

I've been having troubles finding a solution to this problem and eventually come up with one, and as I don't know where to post it I created a question and will answer it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Code assembled with support from this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates)

```kotlin
fun hypersphericalToCartesian(hyperspherical: DoubleArray): DoubleArray {
    val dimension = hyperspherical.size 
    val cartesian = DoubleArray(dimension)
    val r = hyperspherical[0]
    if (r == 0.0) {
        // All cartesian coordinates are zero at the origin
        return cartesian
    }
    var product = r
    var theta = hyperspherical[1]
    for (i in 1..dimension - 2) {
        product *= sin(theta)
        theta = hyperspherical[i+1]
        cartesian[i] = product*cos(theta)
    }
    theta = hyperspherical[1]
    cartesian[0] = r*cos(theta)
    theta = hyperspherical[dimension-1]
    cartesian[dimension - 1] = product*sin(theta)
    return cartesian
}

fun cartesianToHyperspherical(cartesian: DoubleArray): DoubleArray {
    var dimension = cartesian.size
    val hyperspherical = DoubleArray(dimension)
    var r = 0.0
    for (x in cartesian) {
        r += x * x
    }
    r = sqrt(r)
    hyperspherical[0] = r
    if (r == 0.0) {
        // All angular coordinates are zero at the origin
        return hyperspherical
    }

    var theta: Double
    var n = dimension - 1
    var current = cartesian[n]
    var sum = current*current
    for (k in n-1 downTo 1) {
        current = cartesian[k]
        sum+=current*current
        hyperspherical[k]=atan2(1.0,cartesian[k-1]/sqrt(sum))
    }
    theta = cartesian[n]
    theta = 2*atan2(1.0,(cartesian[n-1]+sqrt(cartesian[n-1]*cartesian[n-1]+theta*theta))/theta)
    hyperspherical[n] = theta
    return hyperspherical
}
```

Comment: I am so happy I left it here.

I was searching for it like crazy for a while, knowing that I solved it a while ago =D